# PHP POS (Point Of Sale) not working under GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: php

I am sure this is a common issue. When PHP POS is installed on GoDaddy shared web-hosting it may not work.

The first time I installed it I got the following message: **"No input file specified."**

I followed the setup guide but at the end the POS system did not work because the URL query strings were not resolved properly.

For example, when I made the POS application directory **/pointofsale** (located in my document root) the URL to the PHP POS home page would look like this:

```
http://mystore.com/pointofsale/index.php/home
```

....instead of the properly formatted URL string:

```
http://mystore.com/pointofsale/home
```

After some Googling around, contacting the POS support etc. I managed to make it work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not expand on the GoDaddy webhosting "anomalies" here but this is what worked for me.

Lets say you put all your files into the folder **/pointofsale**

In the **/pointofsale/application/config/config.php** adjust the code as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mystore.com/pointofsale/';

$config['index_page'] = '';  // yes, keep it blank!

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$config['allow_get_array']  = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;

$config['encryption_key'] = 'some_characters_to_sever_as_encryption_string';
```

In the **/pointofsale/index.php** file, keep the following setting:

```
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
```

If the Ajax popup windows for adding/editting customers, items, users etc is giving you a hard time (or shows up blank) edit the file **system/core/Input.php** and try to comment out the LINE 731:

```
//exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
```

Lastly, into your website document root (not in the /point of sale folder) add a **.htaccess** file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pointofsale
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I hope this helps someone, since the PHP POS seems to be very user friendly. Also, since my reputation number did not allow for adding more tags to this post than just PHP, feel fee to re-tag the post.

Comment: :you are saying in the /pointofsale/index.php file, keep the following setting, but i can't find it in pointofsale folder instead i have the index.php under /pointofsale/public folder. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Can you please send me the link where you downloaded the files?

Comment: ...sorry, it has been a while since I was developing this site but I had to purchase the PHP POS  at that time so the current version may not look the same.